# login authentication failure getting LateInitializationError: Field 'loadingBuilder' has not been initialized in flutter

Tags: flutter, authentication, error-handling

```
LoginForm:

    class LoginForm extends StatelessWidget {
      TextEditingController name = TextEditingController();
      TextEditingController pass_word = TextEditingController();
      String? na;
      String? pa;
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return BlocListener<LoginBloc, LoginState>(
          listener: (context, state) {
            if (state.status.isSubmissionFailure) {
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                ..hideCurrentSnackBar()
                ..showSnackBar(
                  const SnackBar(content: Text('Authentication Failure')),
                );
            }
          },
          child: Align(
            alignment: const Alignment(0, -1 / 3),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                BlocBuilder<LoginBloc, LoginState>(
                  buildWhen: (previous, current) =>
                      previous.username != current.username,
                  builder: (context, state) {
                    return TextField(
                      controller: name,
                      key: const Key('loginForm_usernameInput_textField'),
                      onChanged: (name) {
                        na = name;
                        context.read<LoginBloc>().add(LoginUsernameChanged(na!));
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'username',
                        // errorText:
                        //     state.username.invalid ? 'invalid username' : null,
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(12)),
                BlocBuilder<LoginBloc, LoginState>(
                  buildWhen: (previous, current) =>
                      previous.password != current.password,
                  builder: (context, state) {
                    return TextField(
                      controller: pass_word,
                      key: const Key('loginForm_passwordInput_textField'),
                      onChanged: (pass_word) {
                        pa = pass_word;
                        context.read<LoginBloc>().add(LoginPasswordChanged(pa!));
                      },
                      obscureText: true,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'password',
                        errorText:
                            state.password.invalid ? 'invalid password' : null,
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(12)),
                BlocBuilder<LoginBloc, LoginState>(
                  buildWhen: (previous, current) =>
                      previous.status != current.status,
                  builder: (context, state) {
                    return state.status.isSubmissionInProgress
                        ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
                        : ElevatedButton(
                            key: const Key('loginForm_continue_raisedButton'),
                            child: const Text('Login'),
                            onPressed: state.status.isValidated
                                ? () {
                                    print(
                                        '------------------>>>>>>>>>nananan--$na');
                                    print(
                                        '------------------>>>>>>>>>nananan--$pa');
                                    context
                                        .read<LoginBloc>()
                                        .add(LoginSubmitted(na!, pa!));
                                  }
                                : null,
                          );
                  },
                )
              ],
    
  

      Loginstate:

        class LoginState extends Equatable {
          const LoginState({
            this.status = FormzStatus.pure,
            this.username = const Username.pure(),
            this.password = const Password.pure(),
          });
        
          final FormzStatus status;
          final Username username;
          final Password password;
        
          LoginState copyWith({
            FormzStatus? status,
            Username? username,
            Password? password,
          }) {
            return LoginState(
              status: status ?? this.status,
              username: username ?? this.username,
              password: password ?? this.password,
            );
          }
        
          @override
          List<Object> get props => [status, username, password];
        }
        LoginEvent:

        abstract class LoginEvent extends Equatable {
          LoginEvent();
        
          @override
          List<Object> get props => [];
        }
        
        class LoginUsernameChanged extends LoginEvent {
          LoginUsernameChanged(this.username);
          final String username;
          @override
          List<Object> get props => [username];
        }
        
        class LoginPasswordChanged extends LoginEvent {
          LoginPasswordChanged(this.password);
          final String password;
          @override
          List<Object> get props => [password];
        }
        
        class LoginSubmitted extends LoginEvent {
          final String username;
          final String password;
          LoginSubmitted(this.username, this.password);
          @override
          List<Object> get props => [username, password];
        }
            
            LoginBloc:

             LoginBloc({
                required AuthenticationRepository authenticationRepository,
              })  : _authenticationRepository = authenticationRepository,
                    super(const LoginState()) {
                on<LoginUsernameChanged>(_onUsernameChanged);
                on<LoginPasswordChanged>(_onPasswordChanged);
                on<LoginSubmitted>(_onSubmitted);
              }
            
              //final ApiRepository repository;
            
              final AuthenticationRepository _authenticationRepository;
            
              void _onUsernameChanged(
                LoginUsernameChanged event,
                Emitter<LoginState> emit,
              ) {
                final username = Username.dirty(event.username);
                emit(state.copyWith(
                  username: username,
                  status: Formz.validate([state.password, username]),
                ));
              }
            
              void _onPasswordChanged(
                LoginPasswordChanged event,
                Emitter<LoginState> emit,
              ) {
                final password = Password.dirty(event.password);
                emit(state.copyWith(
                  password: password,
                  status: Formz.validate([password, state.username]),
                ));
              }
            
              void _onSubmitted(
                LoginSubmitted event,
                Emitter<LoginState> emit,
              ) async {
                if (state.status.isValidated) {
                  emit(state.copyWith(status: FormzStatus.submissionInProgress));
                  try {
                    await _authenticationRepository.logIn(
                      username: state.username.value,
                      password: state.password.value,
                    );
                    emit(state.copyWith(status: FormzStatus.submissionSuccess));
                  } catch (e) {
                    print(e);
                    emit(state.copyWith(status: FormzStatus.submissionFailure)); //---getting error in this line -------------------------
                  }
                }
              }
            }
    
        Authentication:
        enum AuthenticationStatus { unknown, authenticated, unauthenticated }
        
        class AuthenticationRepository {
          final ApiRepository repository = ApiRepository(
            apiClient: ApiClient(
              httpClient: http.Client(),
            ),
          );
        
          final _controller = StreamController<AuthenticationStatus>();
        
          // AuthenticationRepository(this.repository);
        
          Stream<AuthenticationStatus> get status async* {
            await Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
            yield AuthenticationStatus.unauthenticated;
            yield* _controller.stream;
          }
        
          Future<void> logIn({
            required String username,
            required String password,
          }) async {
            EmpVerifyEntity entity; //---Model class---------
            entity = await repository.loginVerify(emp_id: username, password: password);
    
    //-----api name loginverify----------------------
        
            if (username == entity.employee.empId &&
                password == entity.employee.password) {
              Future.delayed(
                const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                () => _controller.add(AuthenticationStatus.authenticated),
              );
            } else {
              print('------------------------wdawdawdawdawdawdaw-------------------');
            }
          }
        
          void logOut() {
            _controller.add(AuthenticationStatus.unauthenticated);
          }
        
          void dispose() => _controller.close();
        }
```

I'm getting formzStatus.submissionFailure so it shows auhentication failure, I need to hit api and verify the given data after that only it should authenticate but it is giving me an error before that , how to solve this error and make given data to hit api.
..............................---------------------Thank you-------------.................................

Comment: Make sure the variable that you're using is initialised before you use that.